# Google UA enhanced ecommerce: different variable name for ID

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Using GTM and Enhanced eCommerce: I need to track eCommerce on a third-party system and the required ID field is not called ID or transactionID ... it is called confirmID. I'm trying to retrieve a few values from the purchase including transaction amount and cannot use the dataLayer so I'm using a custom JavaScript variable in GTM and have built a tag to read data from the custom variable.

How can I make this work if my ID field name does not match the required ID field name? Here's my JavaScript variable:

```
    function() {
  var ecommerceData = {
    'ecommerce': {
      'purchase': {
        'actionField': {'confirmid':'T123456',
          'tik_value':'500.00',
          'pids':'800911',
          'discounts':'chipster' }


        }
      } 
  };
   return ecommerceData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use proper enhanced ecommerce scheme in your custom JS macro

Correct purchase scheme looks like this:

```
{
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '75.43',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      'products': [{                            // List of productFieldObjects.
        'name': 'Blah T-Shirt',     // Name or ID is required.
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '23',
        'brand': 'Spaceship',
        'category': 'Cool stuffs',
        'variant': 'Bloody red',
        'quantity': 1,
        'coupon': 'esale2015',
        'metric1': 1,
        'dimension2':'Better World'                          
       },
       {
        'name': 'Donut Costume',
        'id': '67890',
        'price': '47.1',
        'brand': 'EatMe & Corp.',
        'category': 'Madman'z gallery',
        'variant': 'Pink with dots',
        'quantity': 1,
        'metric1': 1,
        'dimension2':'Dark Adventure' 
       }]
    }
  }
}
```

### Pass original, wrong formated object into macro

Macro name: {{ECOM_DATA}}.

Related to:

```
 {  
 'ecommerce': {
      'purchase': {
        'actionField': {'confirmid':'T123456',
          'tik_value':'500.00',
          'pids':'800911',
          'discounts':'chipster' 
          } 
      }
  }
```

### Connect wrong formatted data to correct scheme

```
function() {
  var source = {{ECOM_DATA}};
  var transactionData = source.ecommerce[0].actionField;
  var productData = source.ecommerce[0].products;

  var ecommerceData =  {
    'ecommerce': {
      'purchase': {
        'actionField': {
          'id': transactionData.confirmid,                      // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.

          'revenue': transactionData.revenue,                    // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)

          'coupon': transactionData.discounts
        },
        'products': [{                            
          'name': productData.name,     /
          'id': productData.id,
          'price': productData.price,

          'brand': productData.brand,
          'category': productData.cats,
          'variant': productData.modification,
          'quantity': productData.ammount,
          'coupon': productData.coupon,
          'metric1': productData.whatever,
          'dimension2':productData.collection                          
         }]
      }
    }
  }
  return ecommerceData;
}
```

### Further improvements

Think about some input protection (cases when important values are not available ) or date type protection for numeric values, etc...

### Documentation:

**Custom macro for Enhanced Ecommerce:** https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#macro

**Purchase action field description:** https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

Comment: This looks like it may help solve my problem. I'm taking a little time to digest it and test it out. I'll follow-up with results. Thanks!

Comment: I keep getting a parse error, semi-colon expected. And the area of concern seems to be in the var source == {{ECOM_DATA}}; line.  Prior to this I named my custom macro ECOM_DATA and named the macro with this error TDC_ECOMMERCE ... if that matters.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, == is equal operator. There have to be only one = symbol. Names of macros are 100% up to you. I appology for mistake, I did not try the code, I just wrote you an example how it could works.

Comment: Oh no worries at all! I appreciate your feedback so so much! I'll be working on this again shortly and will update.